# G4 - Bluetooth headset and multiple media player

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, lg-g4, poweramp

I have LG G4, 5.1. It came with "Audio" player pre installed. however, I use Poweramp. It works fine 90% of the time. However, occasionally, when I have my BT headset on (LG HBS 750), and press play nothing will happen. At other times, the other media player will start playing. Is there a way to kill any other music players besides poweramp and have my BT send commands directly to poweramp only?